# Find all occurrences of a function in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, how can I find all usages of a function in a Java app? What is the shortcut for that?

I tried with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to search by method, but it return me all methods with the same name.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can find a menu entry in the context menu, when right clicking on the function. You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> when the cursor is above the function or member. Not every project and file type supports this feature. For example, EPIC Perl only supports finding the definition of a function.

Comment: At first I thought that only capital G works, but it seems that Ctrl + SHIFT + G is required

Answer (score 35):

Select a method and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open its **Call Hierarchy** which will show you where the method is being called from.

Answer (score 27):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> for search the whole workspace

Comment: Sadly, this is the only option ("brute force") with PyDev 7.5.0. But it works!

Answer (score 7):

This is hackish, but if you temporarily change the method signature, it will create compile errors, which are easy to find.

Answer (score 4):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to find all uses of a function in the project.

Comment: Its Ctrl+Shift+G to search the function call in the entire workspace ctrl+G is only for the project. In general Ctrl+Shift+L gives all the commands.

Comment: @Manoj That's why I wrote Ctrl-G, and not Ctrl-g

Comment: @tonio Is it somehow possible to search occurrences only in "main" sources, e.g. exclude "test" sources? Or somehow exclude `*Test.java` from search?

Comment: @dma_k I use Working Sets to organise the different types of projects in my workspace. This way, I can search only in test sources, or application source.