# How can I discover which classes implement methods of a class using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working with Eclipse and 2 API. Is there any way I can get information about which classes use a method of a class? For example, I have `gameStarted()` method in Game class, I would like to know other classes who use `gameStarted()` method. I also want to know which classes extend a class and which classes create an instance of a class.

I think I need to know this in order to understand how a part of an API works.

Comment: Something like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850831/find-all-occurrences-of-a-function-in-eclipse ?

Comment: Read the `src.zip` folder in the JDK download, for the source codes of Java standart classes, or read the Javadoc online.

Comment: @Aaron : Sorry I didn't find that question before, its great Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the method name in the source code and choose from the context menu

- `Call hierarchy` to explore all callers and their callers,
- `Declarations` for all places where this method is defined.

Comment: You’re welcome. You should accept the answer. On stackoverflow when you ask a question you should accept the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Call Hierarchy](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/ref-call-hierarchy.htm) will tell you what calls a method or constructor.

[Type Hierarchy](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/ref-call-hierarchy.htm) will tell you what extends a class / what a class extends.